# Symfony2 store database schema information in database tables

Tags: symfony, reflection, doctrine-orm, schema

I need to have my database schema information stored in the database.
I already have a table called db_entity which stores the entity name, namespace and other options.
Related to this table I need to have a table entity_attributes which will have the entity_id,attribute_name,attribute_type,required etc.

Creating the schema structure is easy but inserting all the fields from all my entites in the db would be a tedious work.
Is there any way I can create a script that will parse all my entities annotations, allowing me to create all the fields into my database table?

The best would be to write a similar command to doctrine:schema:update that would update my table schema.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doctrine metadata class http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html contains a public property that could be exactly what you need:

```
 222:     /**
 223:      * READ-ONLY: The field mappings of the class.
 224:      * Keys are field names and values are mapping definitions.
 225:      *
 226:      * The mapping definition array has the following values:
 227:      *
 228:      * - <b>fieldName</b> (string)
 229:      * The name of the field in the Entity.
 230:      *
 231:      * - <b>type</b> (string)
 232:      * The type name of the mapped field. Can be one of Doctrine's mapping types
 233:      * or a custom mapping type.
 234:      *
 235:      * - <b>columnName</b> (string, optional)
 236:      * The column name. Optional. Defaults to the field name.
 237:      *
 238:      * - <b>length</b> (integer, optional)
 239:      * The database length of the column. Optional. Default value taken from
 240:      * the type.
 241:      *
 242:      * - <b>id</b> (boolean, optional)
 243:      * Marks the field as the primary key of the entity. Multiple fields of an
 244:      * entity can have the id attribute, forming a composite key.
 245:      *
 246:      * - <b>nullable</b> (boolean, optional)
 247:      * Whether the column is nullable. Defaults to FALSE.
 248:      *
 249:      * - <b>columnDefinition</b> (string, optional, schema-only)
 250:      * The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.
 251:      *
 252:      * - <b>precision</b> (integer, optional, schema-only)
 253:      * The precision of a decimal column. Only valid if the column type is decimal.
 254:      *
 255:      * - <b>scale</b> (integer, optional, schema-only)
 256:      * The scale of a decimal column. Only valid if the column type is decimal.
 257:      *
 258:      * - <b>unique (string, optional, schema-only)</b>
 259:      * Whether a unique constraint should be generated for the column.
 260:      *
 261:      * @var array
 262:      */
 263:     public $fieldMappings = array();
```